# Symfony2 passing parameters to twig

Tags: symfony, parameters, twig

I'm working with Symfony 2 and I want to pass from my controller to my twig template a simple string and then use it on my template to descriminate the user role.
The controller code has something like :

```
public function modify_user_asAction(Request $request, $username)
{
    $stringtopass="admin";
    $um = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $um->findUserByUsername($username);
    if($user == null){
        //error page here..
    }
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserForm(), $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {     
        $um->updateUser($user);
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_query_success'));
    }
     return $this->render('AcmeUserBundle:Default:modifyuserform.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I want to pass `$stringtopass` in the `generateUrl` (if it's possible).
I can't find anything online. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide the whole action, or at least the return statement ?

Comment: I don't know what you really are trying to do, but if you rely on a client side input to guess the user role, it sound like a nice security issue

Comment: If a user try to access ^/admin or ^/sadmin only and he's not logged in as admin or super_admin he's gonna be redirected to login page

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there!

API: [**generateUrl**](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_generateUrl)

Basically, just pass an `array` as second param to `generateUrl`.

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_query_success', array('stringToPass' => $stringtopass)));
```

And also, **@Brewal** has a very valid point there. Be careful not to pass some sensitive data or leave unrestricted access to that controller's action. You could do more harm than good...

**UPDATE:**

```
public function acmeQuerySuccessAction(){
    // ... action's logic
    $stringToPass = $this->getRequest()->query->get('stringToPass');
    // .....

    return array(
          'stringToPass' => $stringToPass,
          // all other elements that you would normally return
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And how can I use it in twig file?

Comment: That is whole another thing. When you redirect to `acme_query_success` it call another action (let's call it `acmeQuerySuccessAction()`). In there you separately forward request data to `twig`. Updating my answer with appropriate sample...